# Could Stack Exchange get a booth at PAX East next year?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I went to PAX East a while back and thought that Stack Exchange would go over very well there.

There are a number of relevant sites that are out of beta - Gaming, Role Playing Games, and Game Development are all spot on and Sci Fi and Fantasy isn't that far out of the ballpark. If you include Beta sites, Board and Card Games would probably be a huge hit, too. And I just happened to wear my Stack Exchange t-shirt one day and met a few Stack Overflow and Programmers users. Given the content and speakers of PAX East 2012, sites like Fitness (there was a panel for fitness and exercise in video games) and Cognitive Sciences (there were at least one or two panels about the psychological aspects of video games, led by researchers) might also serve well from the advertising.

In general, it might be a great place to plug the entire network to a lot of people. We have sites now that cater to the primary focus of PAX, a number of tangential sites, and access to lots of people (who come in from all around the world for this event).

The next PAX East is going to be held on March 22-24, 2013 in Boston (I believe at the Boston Convention and Exhibition Center, where it was held this year). Although there's no information out yet that I can see, since PAX Prime in Seattle is happening next, this is something that perhaps Stack Exchange can keep on the radar. I'm following PAX East happenings, so if there's interest, I can keep the right people up-to-date.

Comment: I will only support this if Jeff will be our Booth Babe

Comment: @BenBrocka Except PAX banned booth babes. :(

Comment: Jeff is so hot I'm sure they'll allow it

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/new-york-comic-con-2011-gaming-se-involvement#comment8176_2615

Comment: @MattChan Interesting. November 2011 would have been for PAX East 2012, and I didn't see Gaming there. Maybe PAX East 2013.

Comment: @ThomasOwens You could probably e-mail Brett and ask what happened. Maybe this would give us and everyone else some insight into what we could do for next year. Probably doesn't hurt to plan early.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good idea, and one that we've considered before. We're currently working on rebranding the Gaming site, so once that is complete going to conferences like PAX will be even more worthwhile in my opinion. I'm not sure what it would look like to promote multiple SE sites at a conference, but it's a possibility.

I will look into this when we get a little closer to the dates of the conference. Thanks for proposing the idea!

Comment: I'm going to accept this for now. I think promoting would be fairly easy, if you're talking to people. For example, I went to ROFLCon over the weekend and I was talking to someone about the psychology of memes and I mentioned the CogSci Stack Exchange site. If you have someone aware of the different sites and what they are about, it's pretty straightforward to be like "there's a Stack Exchange for that!"